# find commands not executing as intended

Tags: linux, centos, find, pattern-matching

I want to find all files with the filename mask pattern of `filemask1` or `filemask2`, and to exclude the `unwanted*` patterns, that are contained in the specified directories.  I'm trying to run the following:

```
find dir/ other_dir/ parent/child/dir/ parent/child/other_dir/ parent/other_dir/ -iname '*filemask1*' -o -iname '*filemask2*' ! -iname '*unwatned1*' ! -iname '*unwanted2*' ! -iname '*unwanted3*' ! -iname '*unwanted4*'  ! -iname '*unwanted5*' ! -iname '*unwanted6*' ! -iname '*.xls*'
```

I'm executing this from a directory that contains each of the paths that I'm trying to search.  The above gives me all of the files in the specified directories without excluding the unwanted patterns.

```
find dir/ other_dir/ parent/child/dir/ parent/child/other_dir/ parent/other_dir/ \(-iname '*filemask1*' -o -iname '*filemask2*'\) ! -iname '*unwatned1*' ! -iname '*unwanted2*' ! -iname '*unwanted3*' ! -iname '*unwanted4*'  ! -iname '*unwanted5*' ! -iname '*unwanted6*' ! -iname '*.xls*'
```

gives me:

```
find: invalid expression; you have used a binary operator '-o' with nothing before it.
```

While

```
find dir/ other_dir/ parent/child/dir/ parent/child/other_dir/ parent/other_dir/ ! -iname '*unwatned1*' ! -iname '*unwanted2*' ! -iname '*unwanted3*' ! -iname '*unwanted4*'  ! -iname '*unwanted5*' ! -iname '*unwanted6*' ! -iname '*.xls*' \(-iname '*filemask1*' -o -iname '*filemask2*'\)
```

gives me

```
find: paths must precede expression: (-iname
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

Am I missing something regarding how this is getting interpreted?  Is there a way to simplify this so it's not as verbose?  I'm aware that having better filenames would alleviate a lot of the issues, but I am not in control of that :/

A bonus would be if anyone could include a way to prune multiple patterns of directories that would be contained in the directories specified to search in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understand you the answer for your first question is to group wanted and unwanted names separately.

```
find \
dir/ other_dir/ parent/child/dir/ parent/child/other_dir/ parent/other_dir/ \
\( -iname '*filemask1*' -o -iname '*filemask2*' \) \
! \( -iname '*unwatned1*' -o -iname '*unwanted2*' -o -iname '*unwanted3*' -o -iname '*unwanted4*' -o -iname '*unwanted5*' -o -iname '*unwanted6*' -o -iname '*.xls*' \)
```

Also the unwanted dir can be excluded by simple regexp.

Comment: Yes, it's the spaces around the brackets that catches me out. '\( -name' works, but '\(-iname' doesn't.